# How do I add storage to a VM so that the added storage is dedicated to a new directory?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, filesystems, fdisk

I have an Ubuntu server with virt-manager.  I have an Ubuntu VM running on this host from a qcow2 file.  I don't use separate disk files or img files besides the qcow2 file.  I want to allocate 50 GB of new storage space to the VM.

On the VM, df -h has results with a column header of "File Systems" on the left hand side.  I want a dedicated file system of 50 GB to be mounted on /opt/special/.  I want this to be part of the .qcow2 file.

On the physical server, I tried creating a new qcow2 file.  I did so, and created a VM off it.  The VM works, but all the space (including the new 50 GB of extra space that I resized in the new qcow2 file) is in a file system that is part of the original file system mounted on /.  So I don't know how to unmount it to partition it.  I want to take 50 GB from it and dedicate it to its own filesystem (as seen with a df -h).  I tried using libguestfs-tools, qemu-img resize, truncate and other commands to make it work.  Nothing seems to work at the time I create a new, modified qcow2 file.

I tried using the GUI application named Virtual Machine Manager.  But when I added hardware (to add storage capacity as raw disk or a qcow2 file), the VM wouldn't start back up.  I got an error.  What should I do to add 50 GB of space and have it appear under "Filesystem" when I do a df -h and have this 50 GB be mounted on /opt/special/ (a directory that doesn't exist yet)?

I want the 50 GB file system to be mounted on /opt/special/ even after a reboot.

I could try to create an entirely new VM, then within it try to repartition the disk.  Or I could use the virt-* commands to create a new VM with a dedicate partition.  Should I use the virt-* commands or use mkfs.ext3 etc. from within the VM?  Either way, I'm not sure how to proceed (b/c I cannot unmount the / file system, and the virt-* commands only add disk space to the / file system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the VM you want to extend is currently running, all you need, with virt-manager is:

- create the new 50Gb qcow2 storage you want to add
- open the VM's 'hardware detail' panel
- add a new virtual disk using the storage just created.
- reboot the machine: your new storage should appear as /dev/sdb or /dev/vdb depending on disk bus type you are using.
- at this point, you need to use either fdisk or lvm commands and then mkfs to make use or this storage.